# How can I split a string up with whitespace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am having a bit of an issue figuring out how to split a String up with whitespaces between words.

Here is my code

```
let str = "IWantYouToSplitMeUp"; //I want this string to be "I Want You To Split Me Up"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `split` - that will unnecessarily create an intermediate array. Better to use `.replace` alone.

Match characters that are followed by capital letters, then replace that character with that character plus a space:

```js
let str = "IWantYouToSplitMeUp";
console.log(str.replace(/.(?=[A-Z])/g, '$& '));
```

Alternatively, match capital letters that aren't at the beginning of the string, and replace with a space plus that capital letter:

```js
let str = "IWantYouToSplitMeUp";
console.log(str.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, ' $&'));
```